# Query regarding Hyper parameters tuning in deeplearning

Tags: neural-networks, hyperparameter

I have a question "Using an appropriate scale to pick hyperparameters", under the section "Hyperparameter tuning".

The reason mentioned for choosing a log scale over a linear scale for the hyper parameters such as alpha if you choose range between 0.0001 and 1 was that "about 90% of the values you sample would be between 0.1 and 1. So you're using 90% of the resources to search between 0.1 and 1, and only 10% of the resources to search between 0.0001 and 0.1".

I am unable to understand how this is the case because in the linear scale if I understand properly the values

between 0.0001 and 1 would be

0.0001 to 0.1 and 0.1 to 1

the difference between 0.1 and 1 would be 0.9

but the difference between 0.0001 and 0.1 is 0.0999

Is there something I am missing I tried googling a lot and also went through the forum as well. But still I am having a problem

A detail explanation would be helpful

Comment: the difference between 0.1 and 1 is 0.9, not 100

Comment: @shimao: Thanks for pointing out , I have edited my post, Can you please reply to my post